# How to index tag combinations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite

In my project:

- A post has many tags.
- Based on the tags combination, the post is placed in an appropriate category. e.g a post with only the #politics tag shall go to the "General Politics" section and a post with tags #politics and #global will go to the "Global Politics" section
- A table 'categories' stores the categories and the combination(s) of tags those will accept.
- These tags are NOT the only tags the post contains.

**My question is:** What's the best (and economical) way to store and index the tags such that the system can pick up tag combinations easily too. Currently I am storing the tags in a "tags" column in the "posts" table as arrays.

The project is based on RoR 3.2 and sqlite3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and probably the fastest way to accomplish this is by using `searchkick` on the **Posts** model and then including a list of tags a post is tagged with in the search data.

1. Download and install [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/marvel/download/). You need to have jdk installed for it to work.
2. Install [searckick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) gem.
3. Add this to your `post` model:

   ```
   class Post<<ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :title , :body         
    has_many :tags
    searchkick

   def search_data
     attributes.merge(tags: self.tags.map(&:name))
   end
   ```

   Assuming that you hve another `tag` model with the :name attribute
4. To perform queries on combination of tags, just do:

   ```
   Post.search("tag1,tag2",fields:[:tags])
   ```

   These queries are pretty fast, and one may confidently incorporate this logic for purpose of building a navigation structure.

Also see: [Searckick Facets](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#facets)

Answer (score 1):

Using the `acts_as_taggable_on` gem, you can easily query for objects using more than one tag:

```
matching_categories = @post.find_related_tags_for(Category)
```

The resulting list is sorted by decreasing number of matches, probably the first one is the one you want to assign to your post.